# How to create a directory node using the golang etcd client?

Tags: go, coreos, etcd

I would preferably like to have a structure like this in json:

```
{
"a":["b":1, "c":2],
"x":["y":3, "z":4]
}
```

I can work with "a" & "x" as directories & have nodes under them to store data. I cannot find it in the documentation or example of how to get this done.

EDIT: I just created it as a directory by calling the /a/b, /a/c, /x/y & /x/z for Set. This creates the necessary structure, but am looking for a simplified version perhaps to do the same, instead of 4 etcd calls.

Comment: Everything is possible. Usually when you prefer to have fixed keys, you decide to put the data into struct. When keys are not fixed, than you choose map[string]X and X depends on members. In your case - map[string]map[string]int would be enough. But when you don't want to fix depth - it will be map[string]interface{}. And only small notice - please try to think whether you really need so flexible data structure.

Comment: So, the 'key' field needs to have Dir: true in set options and the value can be a struct?

Comment: So, the Dir: true in the client is useful for creating directories. However I still have to make 2 calls for creating directories, and 4 calls for creating the keys. Anyway that this can be done all together?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

to create a directory

`etcdctl mkdir <my_dir>`

to do what you want, there is this option:

`etcdctl set myobject '{"a":["b":1, "c":2],"x":["y":3, "z":4]}'`

will save the json as an object that you can pull back in one call (with `get`)

the key is a string, the value is a string: so you can put anything you want there as long as it's a string... so JSON is a string, and you can put your json string there like anything else.

when you need it back you pull the json string and parse it.

Comment: I have to use the etcd golang client, not the CLI

Comment: then read the code and you will find it:
`mkdirCommandFunc(c, mustNewKeyAPI(c), client.PrevIgnore)`

Comment: Is there a single etcd api call I can make apart from using 4 different calls to get this structure?

Comment: consider etcdctl to be the 'demo' of the etcd client: it does all the client can do.

Comment: Thats an idea. I will look into whether a single etcdctl command can take multiple key values as input and write to the datastore or not.

Comment: you cannot read/ write multiple keys unless you're just listing directories (with `ls --recursive`) but you can save your whole structure as one object and pull it back as one object in one call. then parse the structure in your code.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on how can I save and retrieve entire object in one call?

Comment: the key is a string, the value is a string: you can put anything you want there as long as it's a string... so JSON is a string, and you can put your json string there like anything else. when you need it back you pull the json string and parse it.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't think of it that way. I will do that.

Comment: can you please post your up-voted comment as an answer and I will accept it. Thanks. That really helped.